# What is the syntax for the source element’s type attribute in HTML5?

Tags: html, video

Can someone explain, in simple terms, the syntax for the `type` attribute and `codecs` parameter for the `<source>` element in HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Mark Pilgrim can!

- http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html#markup (scroll down a bit for the `type` attribute on `<source>` elements)

In short:

- the first part of `type` is the video container file’s format (e.g. WebM, MP4)
- the second part (the `codecs` bit) lists the audio and video codecs used to encode the audio and video within the video container file

(If the terms “codec” and “container file” aren’t clear, Pilgrim’s got you covered there too: [video containers](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html#video-containers) and [video codecs](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html#video-codecs).)

To work out what values you should use for video formats not covered by Pilgrim, see http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters.